# How to conditionally map values to new object with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am fetching droplet lists from the DigitalOcean JSON API and using jq map to transform the response into just the info I need.

I want to be able to add an optional key & value pair to my new object, based on whether the response contains a key with a certain value.

When using `select()` if the response doesn't contain a match, the whole droplet entry is removed from my new object, rather than just the key.

How can I filter a single key rather than the whole entry?

In detail:

The response for a single droplet looks like this:

```
 "id": 12345678,
 "name": "my-droplet",
 ...
 "networks": {
      "v4": [
        {
          "ip_address": "123.456.78.90",
          "netmask": "255.255.240.0",
          "gateway": "123.123.0.1",
          "type": "public"
        },
        {
          "ip_address": "10.123.45.67",
          "netmask": "255.255.0.0",
          "gateway": "10.123.0.1",
          "type": "private"
        }
      ],
      "v6": []
    },
 ...
```

I want to transform this into an object of the form:

```
{
  "id": 12345678,
  "name": "my-droplet",
  "public_ip": "123.456.78.90",
  "private_ip" "10.123.45.67"
}
```

All droplets have a public IP, but the private IP is optional.

I have this, which ignores the optional private IP, and works fine so far:

`jq '.droplets | map({id: .id, name: .name, status: .status, public_ip: .networks.v4[] | select(.type=="public") | .ip_address})'`

However, once I add in the private IP, any droplet that doesn't have one goes missing from the response:

`jq '.droplets | map({id: .id, name: .name, status: .status, public_ip: .networks.v4[] | select(.type=="public") | .ip_address, private_ip: .networks.v4[] | select(.type=="private") | .ip_address})'`

I think I need to use concatenation or conditionals some how, but I can't quite figure out the syntax.

Note: I found this similar question, but it doesn't include changing the name of the key: [denormalizing JSON with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148557/denormalizing-json-with-jq)

Comment: For clarity: if there is no private IP then ideally the key would not be present. I have no case where there are multiple private IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t indicate precisely what should happen when there is no private ip (or indeed if there is more than one), but the following should get you on your way.

```jq
.droplets
| map({id, name, status, 
       public_ip: (first(.networks.v4[] | select(.type=="public"))  // {})
                  | .ip_address,
       private_ip: (first(.networks.v4[] | select(.type=="private")) // {})
                  | .ip_address } )
```

#### Conditional key

```jq
def one(condition): first(.[] | select(condition)) // null;

.droplets
| map({id, name, status}
      + (.networks.v4
         | { public_ip: one(.type=="public") | .ip_address}
           + (one(.type=="private") 
              | if . then {private_ip: .ip_address} else null end ) ))
```

Comment: I added a comment to clarify that I was ideally looking to only add the key if it was present - but nulls work as well. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any reference for the `// {}` syntax? I searched the jq manual at length looking for some sort of concept of defaults.

Comment: To avoid the null, you could either use `if then else end`, or delete the key if it is null. `//` is briefly documented in the manual, and more comprehensively in the jq FAQ https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: I tested this solution out in jqplay, and it appears to expand out every possible combination of public vs private IP:

https://jqplay.org/s/7ZvdfPwZ-G

Comment: Corrected parens, and added first()

Comment: Works a treat 

Comment: I wanted to come back and say thanks properly! This example has really helped me to understand how to compose jq programs, I've since been able to process a more complex JSON API example without any trouble. Thank you.