# jq denormalize a nested field

Tags: json, jq

*disclaimer: indeed, there are already different answers (like [JQ Join JSON files by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269833) or [denormalizing JSON with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148557)) for but none of them helped me yet or did have different circumstances I was unable to derive a solution from ;/*

---

I have 2 files, both are lists of objects where one of them ha field references to object ids of the other one

**given**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5b9f50ccdcdf200283f29052",
    "reference": {
      "id": "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1"
    }
  }
]
```

and

```
[
  {
    "id": "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1",
    "name": "FooBar"
  }
]
```

my goal would be to get a denormalized object list:

**expected**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5b9f50ccdcdf200283f29052",
    "reference": {
      "id": "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1",
      "name": "FooBar"
    }
  }
]
```

---

while I'm able to do the main parts, I didn't challenged to bring both together yet:

with
**example 1**

```
jq -s '(.[1][] | select(.id == "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1"))' objects.json referredObjects.json
```

I get

```
{
  "id": "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1",
  "name": "FooBar"
}
```

and with
**example 2**

```
jq -s '.[0][] | .reference = {}' objects.json referredObjects.json
```

I can manipulate any `.reference` getting

```
{
  "id": "5b9f50ccdcdf200283f29052",
  "reference": {}
}
```

(even I loose the list structure)

But: I can't do s.th. like

**execpted "join"**

```
jq -s '.[0][] as $obj | $obj.reference = (.[1][] | select(.id == $obj.reference.id))' objects.json referredObjects.json
```

even approaches with `foreach` or `reduce` looks promising

```
jq -s '[foreach .[0][] as $obj ({}; .reference.id = ""; . + $obj )]' objects.json referredObjects.json
```

=>

```
[
  {
    "reference": {
      "id": "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1"
    },
    "id": "5b9f50ccdcdf200283f29052"
  }
]
```

where I expected to get the same as in second example

I end up in headaches and looking forward to write a ineffective while routine in any language ... hopefully I would appreciate any help on this

~Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution uses the same strategy as used in the solution by @OguzIsmail but uses the built-in function `INDEX/2` to construct the dictionary from the second file.

The important point is that this strategy allows the arrays in both files to be of arbitrary size.

### Invocation

```
jq --argfile file2 file2.json -f program.jq file1.json
```

### program.jq

```
INDEX($file2[]; .id) as $dict
| map(.reference.id as $id | .reference = $dict[$id])
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH @peak, I just simplified it once to just replace the complete .reference object if there are more fields than .name

In additon: what are the known restrictions of not using `--argfile`? From documentation I expect that this would lead to more memory consumption reading all in at once prior processing

+
Documentation says to `--argfile`: `Do not use. Use --slurpfile instead.` but it is not 1:1 replacable, isn't it?!

Comment: The semantics of the two command-line options is different.  If you are uncomfortable using --argfile, by all means use --slurpfile (with the needed minor adjustment to the jq filter), or you could also use the technique in @OguzIsmail's answer.

Comment: I'm not just uncomfortable with, but I don't understand the difference and why --argfile is more robust, just asking ;)

Answer (score 3):

Transform the second file into an object where ids and names are paired and use it as a reference while updating the first file.

```
$ jq '(map({(.id): .}) | add) as $idx
      | input
      | map_values(.reference = $idx[.reference.id])' file2 file1
[
  {
    "id": "5b9f50ccdcdf200283f29052",
    "reference": {
      "id": "5de82d5072f4a72ad5d5dcc1",
      "name": "FooBar"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH @Oguz-Ismail, I just simplified it once to just replace the complete .reference object if there are more fields than .name